# Why are my Javascript callbacks undefined?

Tags: javascript

In an HTML document, a script is run when the page loaded and the JS defines a series of chained together functions, all called whenever the previous one is `done`. I have a number of questions with this example:

1. Why is `f1` undefined?
2. Am I supposed to be able to define functions `f1`, ..., `f4` also within `callbacksInit`, so as not to pollute the global namespace?
3. Am I supposed to be able to define functions
   `f1`, ..., `f4` in the JS document after `callbacksInit`?

```js
var f1 = function() { console.log("Running f1"); }
var f2 = function() { console.log("Running f2"); }
var f3 = function() { console.log("Running f3"); }
var f4 = function() { console.log("Running f4"); }


function callbacksInit() {
    function start() {
        f1()
        .done(f2)
        .done(f3)
        .done(f4);
    }
    start();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./callbacks.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body onload="callbacksInit()">
        <main>
            <h1>CALLBACKS ASYNC</h1>
        </main> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: `f1()` returns `undefined` and you expect it to be a Promise

Comment: your functions dont return anything. But you calling done on the result

Comment: what do I need to return then?

Comment: You need to return a Promise. Or make those `async function`, in which case they will implicitly return a Promise. However, since you don't have any async functionality, I don't know why you want to chain `.done` here.

Comment: it's just an example to outline the structure. the real case uses a DB call.

Comment: Then either return the promise from that DB call (it's most likely a Promise, otherwise you can convert it yourself) or use `async`/`await` for those functions which is basically equivalent but you may prefer to just use `await` everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

a function by itself does not return anything, hence the `undefined`

```js
const a = () => { 
  console.log("Running f1"); 
}

// returns "undefined"
```

```js
const b = () => { 
  console.log("Running f1"); 
  return 'b';
}

// returns "b"
```

**BTW** there is no such thing as `done()` [apart of jQuery deferred mode](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/), but to use that, you need to use jQuery, that's not in the tag

you need to return a `Promise` object, like

```js
function a() {
  return new Promise( function(resolve, reject) {
    // now you can either:
    // return resolve('data')
    // return reject(new Error('My error message'))
  });
}
```

by returning a promise you can now use the normal callback hell ‍♂️

```js
function callbacksInit() {
    function start() {
        f1()
        .then(function(data1) { f2() })
        .then(function(data2) { f3() })
        .then(function(data3) { f4() })
        .then(function(data4) { /* done, continue here */ })
        .catch(function(err) {
           console.log(err.message) // the message of the error upon reject()
        });
    }
    start();
}
```

or use async/await

```js
function callbacksInit() {
    function async start() {
        try { // there's no "catch" in async/await so we wrap all in try/catch
           var data1 = await f1()
           var data2 = await f2()
           var data3 = await f3()
           var data4 = await f4()
       } catch(err) {
           console.log(err.message) // the message of the error upon reject()
       }
    }
    start();
}
```

**Important NOTE**

Always return an `Error` object when rejecting a Promise, will make things so much easier for you in the future

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `f1()` which basically returns void, it doesn't return anything and then you are trying to access a function `done()` it it, but since the return value is undefined then it had nothing.

we are not talking about async functions here or anything, what's wrong with just calling them one after another?

```
f1()
f2()
f3()
f4()
```

This should do the trick, they are not async so each one will just run after the previous one has finished.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Thanks, sure that would be ok, but in my context I have to go async because the `f`s are calling a DB

Answer (score 0):

The function f1 is defined, however the .done called on it is not. In order for you to actually execute the functions one after the other(considering each function has some async actions within it), you need to return Promise from them which resolves once the function is executed.

Also use .then instead of .done

```js
var f1 = function() { console.log("Running f1"); return Promise.resolve()}
var f2 = function() { console.log("Running f2"); return Promise.resolve()}
var f3 = function() { console.log("Running f3"); return Promise.resolve()}
var f4 = function() { console.log("Running f4"); return Promise.resolve()}


function callbacksInit() {
    function start() {
        f1()
        .then(f2)
        .then(f3)
        .then(f4);
    }
    start();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./callbacks.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body onload="callbacksInit()">
        <main>
            <h1>CALLBACKS ASYNC</h1>
        </main> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

For a normal synchronous function, you can  directly call them like

```
function callbacksInit() {
    function start() {
        f1();
        f2();
        f3();
        f4();
    }
    start();
}
```

and they will all execute one after the other

Comment: Do i need jQuery for `Promise.resolve()`? And why `then` instead of `done`?

Comment: No, Promise is a native javascript API